# write a recursive function to format the object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object as follows,

```
x = {
"prop1": {
    "description": "prop1",
    "dataType": "string",
    "value" : "abc"
},
"prop2": {
    "sub1": {
        "description": "sub1",
        "dataType": "integer",
        "value" : 12
    },
    "sub2": {
        "description": "sub2",
        "dataType": "integer",
        "value" : 15
    }
},
"prop3": {
    "input": {
        "name": {
            "description": "Whether to validate input messages",
            "dataType": "boolean",
            "value": false
        }
    },
    "output": {
        "description": "Whether to validate output messages",
        "dataType": "boolean",
        "value": false
    }
}
}
```

I need to convert this object as below.

```
y = {
  "prop1": "abc",
  "prop2.sub1" :12,
  "prop2.sub2" : 15,
  "prop3.input.name" : false,
  "prop3.output" : false,
}
```

I have to create the key name with "." in between prop and sub prop. need to write a recursive function. Any ideas on how to write the recursive function for this?

my code for this.

```
propPrefix = '';
y = {};
function createObject(props){
    Object.keys(props).forEach(prop => {
        const obj = props[prop];
        const hasChildObject = Object.keys(obj).find(key => typeof(obj[key]) == 'object');
        if(hasChildObject){
            propPrefix = propPrefix == "" ? prop + '.' : (propPrefix + '.' + prop);
            createObject(obj);
        }else{
            const value = obj.value;
            y[propPrefix + prop] = value;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution for your problem. I go through each key of the object in each function call and stop if I find a key named `value`, store it in the `obj1` variable

```
x = {
    "prop1": {
        "description": "prop1",
        "dataType": "string",
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "description": "sub1",
            "dataType": "integer",
            "value" : 12
        },
        "sub2": {
            "description": "sub2",
            "dataType": "integer",
            "value" : 15
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "description": "Whether to validate input messages",
                "dataType": "boolean",
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "description": "Whether to validate output messages",
            "dataType": "boolean",
            "value": false
        }
    }
}

function findValue(obj, string, obj1) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
        obj1[string.substring(1)] = obj.value
        return
    }
    for (var key in obj) {
        findValue(obj[key], [string, key].join("."), obj1)
    }
}

var y = {}
findValue(x, "", y)
console.log(y)
```

Result is of the desired format

```
{ prop1: 'abc',
  'prop2.sub1': 12,
  'prop2.sub2': 15,
  'prop3.input.name': false,
  'prop3.output': false }
```